# need a mapping service like google maps - but for my intranet

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps, yahoo-maps

i have built a solution around google maps api but realized that it doesn't work when i deploy it to my intranet.  after reading it seems like you need the premier service for this.  Is there any other similar maps api tools that you can use free on your intranet website?

---

**EDIT:** from what i have read it seems like Yahoo allows you to use your free maps on intranets. can anyone confirm that you are doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up using Yahoo maps as it seems to allow you to use it on your own intranet and its as easy as using google maps

Comment: Yahoo! Maps Web Services is now being shut down by Yahoo. See link: https://developer.yahoo.com/maps/

Answer (score 5):

I would investigate [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/):

- [Content is open](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/License) (Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0)
- There is good [open-source library support](http://www.ns-tech.co.uk/blog/2008/08/using-openstreetmap-overview-part-2-javascript-apis/)

The catch is the data isn't always as accurate or complete, but coverage in major cities is good and the project keeps getting better.

You might also look into Microsoft and Yahoo! mapping licenses.

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon Ovi Maps, a successor to Yahoo Maps as they are taking down their service. Looks quite interesting.

[Yahoo taking down their service](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/)

[Ovi Maps](http://api.maps.ovi.com/devguide/overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at OpenLayers, which enables you to use a variety of different services (Google, OpenStreetMap, Bing etc).

I'm new to it myself, but have found the documentation here:
http://docs.openlayers.org/library/index.html
and here:
http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/index.html
very useful

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go one step further, you can create your [own tile server](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles)

You can easily get what you need from a site like [this](http://www.geofabrik.de)

Answer (score 2):

You can also have a look at http://leafletjs.com/ . While Leaflet aims to be more lightweight than OpenLayers, OpenLayers is by far the more mature project.

See this [Comparison between OpenLayers and Leaflet](http://www.ohloh.net/p/compare?project_0=OpenLayers&project_1=Leaflet)

Answer (score 1):

You could Try pushpin by placebase http://www.pushpin.com/api/1.3/docs/